# How I can calculate standard deviation for rows of a dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

```
df:  

name   group   S1   S2  S3        
A      mn      1    2   8         
B      mn      4    3   5        
C      kl      5    8   2        
D      kl      6    5   5         
E      fh      7    1   3         

output: 

std (S1,S2,S3)
3.78
1
3
0.57
3.05
```

This is working for getting std for a column:

```
numpy.std(df['A'])
```

I want to do the same for rows

Comment: `df.std()` should do what you want

Answer (score 20):

You can use [`DataFrame.std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.std.html), which omit non numeric columns:

```
print (df.std())
S1    2.302173
S2    2.774887
S3    2.302173
dtype: float64
```

If need `std` by columns:

```
print (df.std(axis=1))
0    3.785939
1    1.000000
2    3.000000
3    0.577350
4    3.055050
dtype: float64
```

If need select only some numeric columns, use subset:

```
print (df[['S1','S2']].std())
S1    2.302173
S2    2.774887
dtype: float64
```

There is different with [`numpy.std`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) by default parameter `ddof` (Delta Degrees of Freedom):

- pandas by default `ddof=1`
- numpy  by default `ddof=0`

So there are different outputs:

```
#ddof=1
print (df.std(axis=1))
0    3.785939
1    1.000000
2    3.000000
3    0.577350
4    3.055050
dtype: float64

#ddof=0
print (np.std(df, axis=1))
0    3.091206
1    0.816497
2    2.449490
3    0.471405
4    2.494438
dtype: float64
```

But you can change it very easy:

```
#same output as pandas function
print (np.std(df, ddof=1, axis=1))
0    3.785939
1    1.000000
2    3.000000
3    0.577350
4    3.055050
dtype: float64

#same output as numpy function
print (df.std(ddof=0, axis=1))
0    3.091206
1    0.816497
2    2.449490
3    0.471405
4    2.494438
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

When you can not do on rows whatever you can do on column you may use "transpose"

```
np.std( df.transpose()['S1'] )
```