# Applying several functions on dataframe columns at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How I can apply several functions on Dataframe:

I want to do something similar:

```
features_df[features_columns].apply(lambda x: np.mean(x), lambda x: np.std(x), lambda x: np.skew(x))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) (`pandas 0.20.0+`) or [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
features_df[features_columns].agg(lambda x: pd.Series([np.mean(x),np.std(x)]))

features_df[features_columns].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([np.mean(x),np.std(x)]))
```

---

```
df = features_df[features_columns].agg(['mean', 'std', 'skew'])

df = features_df[features_columns].apply(['mean', 'std', 'skew'])
```

Sample:

```
features_df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                           'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                           'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                           'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                           'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                           'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (features_df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b
```

---

```
features_columns = ['B','C']


print (features_df[features_columns].agg(lambda x: pd.Series([np.mean(x),np.std(x)])))
     B         C
0  4.5  5.500000
1  0.5  2.629956

print (features_df[features_columns].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([np.mean(x),np.std(x)])))
     B         C
0  4.5  5.500000
1  0.5  2.629956

print (features_df[features_columns].agg(['mean', 'std', 'skew']))
             B         C
mean  4.500000  5.500000
std   0.547723  2.880972
skew  0.000000  0.000000

print (features_df[features_columns].apply(['mean', 'std', 'skew']))
             B         C
mean  4.500000  5.500000
std   0.547723  2.880972
skew  0.000000  0.000000
```

`std` function has different default [`ddof`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38361061/2901002) in `numpy` and `pandas`, so  different output.

Also `np.skew` return:

> AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'skew'

Comment: I am getting AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'agg' with your solution.

Comment: Maybe need upgrade pandas, but apply should works nice, only function has to be in list.